# integration between formly and quill

Tags: angular, angular-material, quill, ngx-quill, ngx-formly

I use [formly](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/) to render a reactive form with Angular material.
now I try to replace a normal textarea field with [quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill) (a text editor for angular)

both formly and quill works fine separately, but the issue is with including a quill editor as a formly field.

**what I already tried:**

```
this.fields=[
{
      key: "Quill",
      template: "<b>Quill:</b> <quill-editor></quill-editor>", //only <b>Quill</b> rendered
    },
    {
      key: "Quill2", 
      component: QuillEditorComponent, //hasn't been rendered
    },
  {
      key: "Quill3",
      type: "quill" //a custom type
    }
]
```

none of the methods above worked!

I don't want to make separate parts of formly, like that:

```
<formly-form [fields]="articleForm.fields1"></formly-form>
<quill-editor></quill-editor>
<formly-form [fields]="articleForm.fields2"></formly-form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just follow https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field and you'll be able to create ngx-quill type (here is a quick attempt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elwtix.)